# Is there an equivalent to SSLLabs' SSL test for SSL/TLS that is not HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, tls

I've used [SSL Labs' SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) for testing SSL setup for HTTP servers, but it doesn't support other situations in which SSL is used, such as IMAP. Is there an equivalent detailed test for non-HTTP servers using SSL? I've used [SSL Shopper's SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) for a basic test, but it doesn't go into details like whether it's correctly configured for Perfect Forward Secrecy etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh/). This is a bash script rather than a web service, but it is under active development and can test STARTSSL services.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at

- [Nessus](https://www.tenable.com/products/nessus/nessus-professional), which is (according to Wikipedia) "a proprietary comprehensive vulnerability scanner which is developed by Tenable Network Security. It is free of charge for personal use in a non-enterprise environment",
- [sslscan](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan), which tests SSL/TLS enabled services to discover supported cipher suites,
- [ssl_tests](http://www.pentesterscripting.com/discovery/ssl_tests), which is a bash script that uses `sslscan` and `openssl` to check for various flaws - ssl version 2, weak ciphers, md5withRSAEncryption,SSLv3 Force Ciphering Bug/Renegotiation (although the website seems down). [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130703093326/http://www.pentesterscripting.com/discovery/ssl_tests) you'll find a cached version of the website provided by the Internet Archive.